# Iphone battery charging with other gear

Tags: iphone

A few minutes ago I needed to charge my iphone 4. I had the apple USB cable but not my wall adapter (sorry, I'm from Portugal and I don't master all the terms!).

I found that my eGo cigarette charger had just that missing part, just on a different collor. It seemed to me that the pecs where the same, so I tried it.

A few minutes latter I hear a click and the iphone stopped charging and a slight burn sent got in the air. The e-cigarette stoped working. Probably broke!

The question is. Do you think my iphone battery  got compromised with this? I ended up charging the rest directly from the PC USB port.

---

PS:
Specs on e-cigarette charger
Input: 100 - 240V - 50/60 Hz 0.15A
Output: 5V ---500mA

Answer (score 1):

Not clear who and what smoked in your question.

I presume the ezig charger got fried since it was overloaded.

A word to the specs:

5 volt is 5 volt,however the problem could be the current.

The iPhone will take as much as it gets up to 1 Amp.

[image]

If your ezig charger did not have a current limiter (like the USB on you Mac have) then it got overloaded.

Since you continued charging the iPhone using the Mac USB, you might be OK.